# firefox @keyframes solution

Tags: css, firefox, animation, placeholder

Hello i am using css3 to animate place holder i figured out to run this on webkit navigators but firefox and  ie the animation doesn't work and i think the problem is @keyframes please guys any solution guys ?

```
input::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #8D8D8D;
}
input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #8D8D8D;
}
input:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #8D8D8D;
}

input:focus::-moz-placeholder {
animation-duration: 0.4s;
animation-name: slidein;
animation-timing-function: ease-out;
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
animation-delay: 0.1s;
}
input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  -webkit-animation-name: slidein;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.1s;
}
input:focus:-ms-input-placeholder {
  opacity: 0;
}

input {
  color: black;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slidein {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
    padding-left: 0px;
  }

  to {
    opacity: 0;
    padding-left: 10px;
  }
}
@keyframes slidein {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 10px;
  }

  to {
    opacity: 0;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 0px;
  }
}
```

this is live demo http://jsfiddle.net/Cd8MG/

Comment: up up no one has a solution ? :'(

Answer (score 0):

you need @-ms-keyframes, @-moz-keyframes, @-webkit-keyframes, and @keyframes to cover all of your bases. Yes, your code will be 10 miles long.

Comment: You Mean like this ? http://jsfiddle.net/Cd8MG/2/ samething (note:this is for mozilla only and should work) and my code work like acharm on chrome and safari + opera but not firefox :/

Comment: Ok, so first of all you really don't need keyframes. Secondly, Firefox apparently does not allow transitioning things on a placeholder which is too bad. But, it is still usable in FF and transitions in better browsers: http://jsfiddle.net/Cd8MG/3/  Read the comment threads here for other people's experiences: http://css-tricks.com/hang-on-placeholders/

Answer (score 0):

Ok My final conclusion is :
No one seems to have noticed, but in Firefox the behavior of the placeholder attribute is to leave the text until the user begins typing, at least in the most recent versions. Webkit solutions (or should I say -webkit solutions) to Webkit problems don’t seem to last long these days.